# how to make an ajax request after sending data by post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i meet a problem, when try to make an ajax request after sending data by post.

let's assume i have a index.php file. In the form i send data by post to the same file, and after posting i want to make ajax request, but it don't doesn't happen, because it "wants" to ask  about resending data, but it doesn't show in popup window.

So, how can i disable the question about resending data, to be possible to make an ajax request?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide code that is relevant?

Comment: the script is big, it just blocking ajax request, because trying to ask the question about resending data. here is that message - "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Answer (score 1):

That would not happen . Once you are posting data you are actually reloading your entire page . If you want to do an AJAX call after the post , you should consider making the post request as ajax as well .

So currently if what you are doing is : 
Step 1 : Post data to index.php 
Step 2 : Make AJAX call

you should consider restructuring it to : 
Step 1: Make a XHR call to post data 
Step 2 : Make another XHR call .

Another way to do this is that in the Page returned after the post request , you can set a cliest side js variable , and the on document load , you can fire the AJAX request , however I dont think that is what you are looking for .